# How to open remote folders in Dolphin

Tags: server, ssh, kubuntu, remote-access, dolphin

We have multiple repositories on our server, that we can only compile and run on that server. I have a XUbuntu machine and on Thunar I mount the remote folder with ssh://myname@server.domain. Then, the remote folder will automatically appear in "Other Locations" in Thunar, and I can edit the files on the remote machine with my local editor. Look at the following screenshot (notice the network folder in "Open Folder" dialog box):

[image]

I recently installed KUbuntu on another machine, and after I mount the remote folder on Dolphin, the remote folder is not automatically added to "Other Locations". And I cannot edit the remote files in a local editor. Look at the following picture:

[image]

Is there any way to mount the remote folder similar to Thunar in Dolphin, so that I can edit the files in a local editor. BTW, This [post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/save-as-from-any-browser-does-not-show-network-mapped-drives/63361) reports a similar problem, which is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sshfs (ssh as a file system)

```
sudo  apt install sshfs
mkdir /mnt/server
sshfs  servername:/  /mnt/server
```

and try to access /mnt/server with Dolphin or any other program

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, this is what I am doing now.